# Shutdown, restart and suspend problems on Acer E5 511 (Sandy Bridge) 14.04 and 15.04

Tags: uefi, suspend, shutdown, acer, restart

Lot's of similar problems out there. Basically I have tried most or all of the suggestions offed but to no avail.

Specifically. I installed Unity 15.04 on two Acer E5 511 C1WE laptops and it seems to work great in UEFI with secure boot turned off, a bit shaky in legacy, seems more flickery and unstable in boot up, but it still works fine, both modes on both laptops suffer from the same problem as follows:

Shutdown, restart and suspend all require me to hard restart, screen goes dark and I get this message:

```
[ OK ] Started Light Display Manager.
[ OK ] Started ACPI event daemon.
       Starting ACPI event daemon...
       Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service....
[ OK ] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
```

system then tries to reboot and hangs. I hard Shutdown with the button.When I restart typically it will hang again, sometimes even twice before I get a clean boot. I get GRUB options and sometimes not?

I have two identical laptops here and I am getting consistent results from both so I can count out it just being this unit.

Anyway I would be happy to provide more info. I am quietly hopping that this will get sorted soon in an update, as it seems to be a broad sweeping issue. But as a recent convert to Ubuntu I can't assume that?

Thanks!

Comment: Update ! I just updated the BIOS to 1.08 from 1.03. It seems to have made no difference to the shutdown issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer no guarantees on this, but you might look into the `reboot=` kernel option. As documented in the kernel source tree's `Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt` file:

```
reboot=         [KNL]
                Format (x86 or x86_64):
                        [w[arm] | c[old] | h[ard] | s[oft] | g[pio]] \
                        [[,]s[mp]#### \
                        [[,]b[ios] | a[cpi] | k[bd] | t[riple] | e[fi] | p[ci]] \
                        [[,]f[orce]
                Where reboot_mode is one of warm (soft) or cold (hard) or gpio,
                      reboot_type is one of bios, acpi, kbd, triple, efi, or pci,
                      reboot_force is either force or not specified,
                      reboot_cpu is s[mp]#### with #### being the processor
                                to be used for rebooting.
```

To use these options, you'll need to edit your GRUB (or other boot loader) configuration. You can do this on a one-time basis in GRUB by hitting `e` rather than Enter to launch your kernel. This will give you a simple text editor in which you can change the kernel options. If you find something that works, use [GRUB Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) to set it up permanently.

If you use something other than GRUB, you'll need to consult the program's documentation to learn how to make changes. (Most make it easier than GRUB to customize settings, at least if you're comfortable editing configuration files.)

Comment: Thanks Rod,  I haven't heard of this fix yet. I can't say I am comfortable editing configuration files. But I do get the general idea of what you are saying. When I get brave enough I will try your suggestion and let you know how it goes. Bit scared of losing my system again.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I think I now understand basically what you are suggesting. A couple of things that aren't clear to me. 

The line "reboot_cpu is s[mp]#### with #### being the processor". Do I need to add something here?

Also, do I add the above code after the code that exists in the Grub text editing area or replace it?

Thanks!

Comment: Add the `reboot=???` option you intend to test; do not remove existing options unless you know what they do and intend to remove them. (Removing `quiet splash` will result in more verbose startups and shutdowns, which might conceivably give you a hint about what's going on.) As to the `s[mp]####` option, it sounds like the number refers to the CPU that you want to put in charge of the reboot, but I'm not 100% sure of that.

Comment: I am unfortunately just starting with Ubuntu, and just wouldn't know what to put in as cpu. I would like to continue with this route, maybe some one else knows, any leads?